# Hyperbolic Trig Inequality

Tags: inequality, hyperbolic-functions

The following [hyperbolic trig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_analytic_expressions) inequality came up.
$$0 \leq y \leq x \leq 2 \implies \sinh(x)-\sinh(y) \leq \sinh(x-y)\cdot e^{xy/2}.$$

I spent many hours trying to prove it. The first few terms of the Taylor series work out, but I couldn't get a general proof. I passes the usual sanity checks ($y=0$, $y=x$, $x=2$) and I also verified it numerically by plotting and checking about $10^9$ random $x$ and $y$ values.

Any ideas?

Comment: $$0 \leq y \leq x \leq 2$$
$$\sinh(x)-\sinh(y) \leq \sinh(x-y)\cdot e^{xy/2}$$
$$e^x-e^{-x}+e^{-y}-e^y \leq [e^{x-y}-e^{y-x}]e^{xy/2}$$
$$\frac{e^x-e^{-x}+e^{-y}-e^y}{e^{x-y}-e^{y-x}} \leq e^{xy/2}$$
$$\frac{e^{x+y}+1}{e^x+e^y} \leq e^{xy/2}$$
$$e^{x+y}+1\leq (e^x+e^y) e^{xy/2}$$

Comment: I get stuck there, but I feel like the solution should be right around the corner

Comment: This should hold for all $x,y > 0$ graphically. Anyone have any suggestions to complete the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Completing [Brevan Ellefsen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/269764/brevan-ellefsen)'s solution.

First, since
$\sinh x - \sinh y = 2 \sinh \frac{x-y}{2} \cosh \frac{x+y}{2}$,
and
$\sinh (x-y) = 2 \sinh \frac{x-y}{2} \cosh \frac{x-y}{2}$,
we have
$$
r\equiv\frac{\sinh x - \sinh y}{\sinh (x-y)}
= \frac{\cosh \frac{x+y}{2} } {\cosh \frac{x-y}{2}}
= \frac{1 + \tanh\frac x 2 \tanh \frac y 2 } { 1 - \tanh\frac x 2 \tanh\frac y 2}.
$$
For $0 \le \dfrac{x}{2}, \dfrac{y}{2} \le 1$, we have
$$
0
\le
\tanh\frac{x}{2} \cdot \tanh\frac{y}{2}
\le
\frac{x}{2} \cdot \tanh\frac{y}{2}
\le
\tanh\left(\frac{x}{2} \cdot \frac{y}{2}\right) \le 1.
$$
Since $\dfrac{1+t}{1-t}$ is an increasing function of $t$ for $t \in (0, 1)$, we get
$$
r \le \frac{1 + \tanh\frac{xy}{4}}{1-\tanh\frac{xy}{4}}
=\exp\frac{xy}{2}.
$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I have cited it in a paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1605.02065/

Comment: @Thomas, wow, so glad it helped! The honor is all mine. Congratulations on your fine paper!